# After many attempts, The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, datasource, shared, ssrs-2008-r2

We have an SSRS report that connects to an SSAS cube. The report and the Data Source (to the SSAS cube) had been deployed. Unfortunately, nobody could see the report (error: either the user does not have access to the DB or the DB does not exist).

After many changes to the datasource, I deleted the datasource and I received a `rsInvalidDataSourceReference`, which is correct. I then deleted the report.

Once I deleted both of them I cleared IE's cache. Then I redeployed both the report and the datasource, and went to the report's properties to make sure it was pointing to the correct datasource. I have not made any changes to the datasource so I should now get the user access error.

Unfortunately, I continue getting an `rsInvalidDataSourceReference`. I've done this many times (deleted & redeploying datasource and report) but still nothing.

What can the problem be? At the very least I should get denied connection error once again.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues like this with no reason or solution.

The workaround was to manually set the datasource in Report Manager.  :(

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f06e400-e803-4070-b272-4eb5d3d55efd/rsinvaliddatasourcereference-error?forum=sqlreportingservices

http://ok-sandbox.com/2013/12/ssrs-fix-rsinvaliddatasourcereference/